# Delay email sending in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, queue, rubygems, delayed-job

I am using delayed_job to delay sending information from my application to FreeagentCentral (an accountancy package). At the same time it also sends two emails using PostmarkApp's gem.

```
# POST /kases
# POST /kases.xml
def create
@company = Company.find(params[:kase][:company_id])
@kase = @company.kases.create!(params[:kase])

respond_to do |format|
UserMailer.delay.deliver_makeakase("email@address.com", "Highrise", @kase) if    params[:sendtohighrise]
UserMailer.delay.deliver_makeakaseteam("email2@address.com", "Highrise", @kase) if params[:notify_team_of_creation]
@kase.delay.create_freeagent_project(current_user) if params[:send_to_freeagent]

#flash[:notice] = 'Case was successfully created.'
flash[:notice] = fading_flash_message("Case was successfully created.", 5)

format.html { redirect_to(@kase) }
format.xml  { render :xml => @kase, :status => :created, :location => @kase }
end
end
```

The above code doesn't throw any errors - but the emails don't get sent. I was wondering if I have done something wrong?

Should it be like this, or am I missing something:

```
UserMailer.delay.deliver_makeakaseteam("email2@address.com", "Highrise", @kase) if params[:notify_team_of_creation]
```

Thanks,

Danny

UPDATE

```
--- 
- !ruby/object:Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job 
  attributes: 
    created_at: 2011-02-21 13:30:38
    locked_by: 
    failed_at: 
    updated_at: 2011-02-21 13:30:38
    handler: |
      --- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMethod 
      object: LOAD;UserMailer
      method: :deliver_makeakase
      args: 
      - email@email.com
      - Highrise
      - LOAD;Kase;19

    priority: "0"
    id: "1"
    run_at: 2011-02-21 13:30:38
    locked_at: 
    attempts: "0"
    last_error: 
  attributes_cache: {}

- !ruby/object:Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job 
  attributes: 
    created_at: 2011-02-21 13:30:38
    locked_by: 
    failed_at: 
    updated_at: 2011-02-21 13:30:38
    handler: |
      --- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMethod 
      object: LOAD;UserMailer
      method: :deliver_makeakaseteam
      args: 
      - email@email.com
      - Highrise
      - LOAD;Kase;19

    priority: "0"
    id: "2"
    run_at: 2011-02-21 13:30:38
    locked_at: 
    attempts: "0"
    last_error: 
  attributes_cache: {}

=> nil
```

Comment: Are they making it to the delayed jobs table? If so, are they being locked and run? Are they storing errors in there (DJ will store exceptions from running the code in the table)? Is the delayed job worker running?

Comment: The worked must be running for the Freeagent job to complete, shouldn't it? How do I check the jobs table?

Comment: Yeah, if the other job is working, DJ is running. You can check the jobs table however you like - it's just a table in the db. You could use rails console.. run `y Delayed::Job.all`

Comment: ok, the emails are showing up in the console. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

from (collectiveidea)  delayed_job docs

> Due to how mailers are implemented in
>   Rails 3, we had to do a little work
>   around to get delayed_job to work.
>
> without delayed_job

```
Notifier.signup(@user).deliver
```

> with delayed_job

```
Notifier.delay.signup(@user)
```

> Remove the .deliver method to make it
>   work. It’s not ideal, but it’s the
>   best we could do for now.

hope this could help

Comment: Sadly not, it's a Rails 2.3 application. Thanks anyway!